# Compliance Info and Release notes are not updated in App Store

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, app-store, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

I am trying to submit app using appcenter but I am getting below error :

**Oops! Compliance Info and Release notes are not updated in App Store. Alternatively, you can set 'ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption' flag in info.plist and redistribute**

I have also re-tried adding below key, and I am still getting same error

```
<key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key> 
<false/>
```

Comment: Hi , you can generate the ipa file , and have a check with **Application Loader** to distribute it to see whether it works .

Comment: I ran into the same issue last night.  There are some compliance questions you have to fill out about encryption information and export laws.  I had my buddy with a Mac submit the IPA via transporter and it worked.  I still can't do it via appcenter.

Comment: The same issue here, with Cordova app (not Xamarin), deploying from Azure Pipeline through AppCenter Distribute function. Looking into fastlane logs, it seems to me it is more something between fastlane and AppStore.